# CharSequence defining multiple words?

Tags: java, charsequence

```
CharSequence listOfWords = ("word");
```

the code above successfully defines `listOfWords` as: "`word`"
But I need `listOfWorlds` to have lots of words in it, not just the single "`word`".

```
CharSequence listOfWords = ("word")("secondword");
```

above code is what I want, but obviously incorrect.

I'd like to be able to call `listOfWords` and have it be defined as "word" OR "secondword". Is `CharSequence` even the correct variable here? Any help?

Comment: A `CharSequence` is a sequence of characters, like its name says; it won't "store" words. Also, if you look a little more carefully, you'll see that 1. methods of this interface are pretty much telling you that already, and 2. `String` implements `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off using a List of String(s).  For reference, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html, you can see that `String` implements `CharSequence`

```
public static void main(String eth[]) {
    List<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfWords.add("word");
    listOfWords.add("secondWord");
    listOfWords.add("thirdWord");

    // You use your list as followed
    System.out.println(listOfWords.get(0)); // .get(0) gets the first word in the List
    System.out.println(listOfWords.get(1)); // .get(1) gets the second word in the List
    System.out.println(listOfWords.get(2)); // .get(2) gets the third word in the List
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: @Tom Copy & Paste is a horrible thing :-)...  Thanks